# How to integrate terraform with atlassian/localstack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, localstack

Terraform can be configured with [custom S3 endpoints](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/#s3) and it seems that [localstack](https://github.com/atlassian/localstack) can create local stacks for S3, SES, Cloudformation and few others services.

The question is what to write in Terraform configuration to use localstack's S3 endpoint?

Answer (score 13):

Terraform does not officially support "AWS-workalike" systems, since they often have subtle quirks and differences relative to AWS itself. However, it is supported on a best-effort basis and may work if localstack is able to provide a sufficiently realistic impression of S3 for Terraform's purposes.

According to the localstack docs, by default the S3 API is exposed at `http://localhost:4572` , so setting the custom endpoint this way may work:

```
provider "aws" {
  endpoints {
    s3 = "http://localhost:4572"
  }
}
```

Depending on the capabilities of localstack, you may need to set some other settings:

- `s3_force_path_style` to use a path-based addressing scheme for buckets and objects.
- `skip_credentials_validation`, since localstack seems to lack an implementation of the AWS token service.
- `skip_metadata_api_check` if IAM-style credentials will not be used, to prevent Terraform from trying to get credentials from the EC2 metadata API.

Answer (score 11):

Building off @martin-atkins’ answer, here’s a sample Terraform file that works with Localstack:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  access_key = "anaccesskey"
  secret_key = "asecretkey"
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_metadata_api_check = true
  s3_force_path_style = true
  endpoints {
    s3 = "http://localhost:4572"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  bucket = "my-tf-test-bucket"
  acl    = "public-read"
}
```